# Algolia Prefix Matching

Tags: typeahead.js, algolia

I have a record 'ABC756'

How do I make it match the query in typeahead.js

```
756
```

It only matches when I type

```
  ABC
```

My settings

```
{"params":"query:756
  hitsPerPage:15
  restrictSearchableAttributes: attr
  queryType:prefixAll"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most search engines, Algolia doesn't *natively* support substring & suffix matching. What you can do is preprocess your objects to generate all the substrings (or suffices) required. It's explained here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/toubleshooting/how-can-i-make-queries-within-the-middle-of-a-word